# How to convert list to json?

Tags: json, django, list

I have a queryset;

```
   queryset = tagReferenceLocationInfo.objects.select_related('ref').filter(tag_id__in=id_list, date__gte=startDate, date__lte=endDate)
```

I got this queryset result data as a list;

```
data = list(queryset)
```

This data contains referanceName inside ref object.

[image]

I use;

data = serialize('json', allObj)

I can get only "ref" value;

```
[{"model": "equipment.tagreferencelocationinfo", "pk": 10015778, "fields": {"tag": 13, "ref": 26, "map": 1, "corX": 469, "corY": 295, "date": "2021-04-29T06:30:52.032Z"}}, {"model": "equipment.tagreferencelocationinfo", "pk": 10015812, "fields": {"tag": 13, "ref": 26, "map": 1, "corX": 473, "corY": 297, "date": "2021-04-29T06:31:02.507Z"}}]
```

I want to get also "referanceName" inside this data. How can add it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method from json library

```
import json

jsonString = json.dumps(list)
```

Comment: This will not work since it's a queryset object which json.dumps does not know how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a serializer.

```py
from django.core.serializers import serialize

queryset = tagReferenceLocationInfo.objects.select_related('ref').filter(
    tag_id__in=id_list,
    date__gte=startDate,
    date__lte=endDate
).values(
    'ref__referanceName'
)

serialize('json', queryset)
```

Comment: I edited my answer, not sure if it will work but try it. You might have to change to string to fit your model, im not sure how yours look like

Comment: Thanks again I also use it but ı get 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta' error. Actually, that's why I asked here.I do not know what I am missing.